# DIEHARDER test suite build is broken for Arch Linux

Tags: linux, random, archlinux, test-suite

I've created a PRNG for an university project and I need to test it with the DIEHARDER test suit. Unfortunatelly, every way I tried to install it in my Arch Linux gets failed.

First I tried from the AUR package ([dieharder](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dieharder), dieharder-git and dieharder-bin) and all of those gives error when downloading the files from github. When you try to enter the [github address](https://github.com/christopherkobayashi/dieharder), it gives the 404 error.

Then I tried downloading from the [official website](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php). I've tried a lot of versions (3.31.1, 3.31.0, 2.6.24, 2.27.13, 2.24.7 and 2.24.1) and all of those gives error when trying to install it via ./configure and makefiles, and the errors are often based on headers and variables not properly declared in the build, just as "ckoba" commented on the official aur repository website:

> For what it's worth, I spent several hours this afternoon moving variable declarations from .h files to .c files, eliminating the duplicate variable issues that broke the build.
> While I was at it, I updated the autoconf bits so that the build framework properly detects modern platforms. I've tested this on i686, x86_64, and aarch64 platforms, and all seem to work fine.

Does someone knows how to install it in my Arch Linux distro today in August 2023? I really need it to test my PRNG and I'm struggling for days trying to install it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kudos for all you hard work (that was coding), but sorry, but Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code problems (you seemed to have solved that on your own!). IMHO, your question seems to be about using and configuring a build for Arch LInux. Please delete here and to repost to [unix.se] . Good luck!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952696/how-do-i-execute-dieharder-tests-in-windows-11#75972032) is someone asking just the same but in a Windows machine, and getting properly answer here on Stack Overflow. I even tried to follow that though but didn't worked in my Arch Linux. Thank you @shellter for your recommendation, I'll post there, but won't delete here.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it, following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952696/how-do-i-execute-dieharder-tests-in-windows-11#75972032) steps and adding a sudo in the line `sudo make install`

Comment: excellent reference, but please do also embed the exact steps you took!